# activerecord without Rails: get related records

Tags: ruby, oracle, activerecord, jruby

I'm trying to use a relationship between tables, 
the primary key in both tables has the same name adm_id
(i know, i know, but have no control over the db)
I use activerecord without Rails in JRuby.

When i get the related records (the emails) i get the error below.
Could somoene help me out ?

```
require 'java'
require 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter'
require "C:/jruby-1.7.4/bin/ojdbc14.jar"
Java::OracleJdbcDriver::OracleDriver

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
   :adapter => 'jdbc',
   :driver => 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver',
   :url => 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxxx:xxxx:xxx',
   :username=>'xxx',
   :password=>'xxx'
 )

class Adm < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'scheme1.db_all'
  self.primary_key = 'adm_id'
  has_many :emails
end

class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'scheme2.db_email'
  self.primary_key = 'adm_id'
  belongs_to :adm, :foreign_key => 'adm_id'
end

lid = Adm.where(adm_id: 99999999).take(1) #ok
email = Email.where(adm_id: 99999999).take(1) #ok
p lid.emails

#error: NoMethodError: undefined method `emails' for #<Array:0x19bc716>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a single record, don't pass any arguments to `take`:

```
lid   = Adm.where(adm_id: 3441029).take
email = Email.where(adm_id: 3441029).take
p lid.emails
```

If any argument is supplied to `take`, even if it's 1, an array of results is returned.

Comment: pat: the two takes are just there to check if at least one record exists, and they work as i indicated. I'm new to these packages but i presume they have nothing to do with the relationship that i'm trying to use by showing lid.emails
and when you use take without parameters yout get the following error in JRuby 1.7.4: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments calling `take` (0 for 1)

Comment: If you want a single record from the query, better to use `first` rather than `take`, and then try calling `emails` on the resulting Adm instance: `Adm.where(adm_id: 3441029).first.emails` - or even simpler, given you're searching by primary key: `Adm.find(3441029).emails`